# How to get max_score in a query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I am new to elastic search, I was wondering how I could get the `max_score` of my first query and then compare it to the rest of the values. For example if the `max_score` was 2.6 I would want to take that value and compare it with the `_score` of all the docs in the query.

```
GET searchentities/_search
{
  "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "iron man",
          "type": "bool_prefix",
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "title._2gram",
            "title._3gram"
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 2
        }
      }
}
```

**Gives back the following:**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.4475412,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "searchentities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IronMan",
        "_score" : 2.4475412,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "Iron Man",
          "ad" : false,
          "verified" : false,
          "clicks" : 2,
          "photoID" : "5f8a9dd82ab79c00017722bb",
          "title" : "Iron Man "
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "searchentities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IronMan3",
        "_score" : 2.2448254,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "Iron Man 3 ",
          "ad" : false,
          "verified" : false,
          "clicks" : 2,
          "photoID" : "5f8a9dd82ab79c00017722bb",
          "title" : "Iron Man 3 "
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "searchentities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IronMan2",
        "_score" : 2.2448254,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "Iron Man 2 ",
          "ad" : false,
          "verified" : false,
          "clicks" : 20,
          "photoID" : "5f8a9dd82ab79c00017722bb",
          "title" : "Iron Man 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**I would want to see**

```
2.44-2.44 =  0 
2.44-2.24 = .2
2.44-2.24 = .2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to post process the score in this way in elastic.
The max score is just the highest score after all scores have been calculated.
This values is not available in the postprocess possibilities that exists in Elasticsearch.

See:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-max-score-inside-script-function/156871/3

I think you have to write your own program processing the result and returning the difference between scores.